# Visual Studio 2010 stopped displaying IntelliSense suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having an issue with my Visual Studio 2010 IntelliSense, which stopped working recently.
It had worked earlier.
I had gone through the following steps

**[Visual Studio C# IntelliSense not automatically displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420303/visual-studio-c-sharp-intellisense-not-automatically-displaying)** 
but that too not worked on my system.
Here I am attaching the screenshot for your reference,
[image]

Thanking in advance

Comment: Is this just on one project or all projects/files?

Comment: does intellesense work if you create a new xaml?

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart , its happening with all my projects, had worked earlier.

Comment: @John Faulkner, not works in my entire visual studio 2010, i tried xml and even in c# code file.

Comment: What happens if you Reset your VS settings? (Tools > Import and Export Settings)

Comment: @Dai , When i rest the visual studio, still showing the same result.

Comment: It sounds to me like your IntelliSense backing databases are corrupted. If this was C++, I'd say to delete your NCB file. In .NET languages, I'd say you could clean and rebuild the solution. But I'm not really sure about HTML. Is that InteliSense even built in, or do you have to download an extension for it? Perhaps you could re-apply the extension.

Comment: @Cody Gray, it was worked earlier in my visual studio. so i think it's not needed to use additional extension. As you have mentioned i tried rebuid the solution, again the issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known feature/bug (feature with a bug?), which can be resolved by restarting Visual Studio.

It appears, that this behaviour is shown by Visual Studio if you press Ctrl + Alt + Space.
I'd recommend resetting your setting like Dai suggestested, if a VS-retart does not work.

Additional information:
[VS2010 Bug: Intellisense shows empty text field and stops working correctly](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587691/vs2010-bug-intellisense-shows-empty-text-field-and-stops-working-correctly)

Comment: This doesn't look like the same bug you're talking about. The member list box is *entirely blank*. Ctrl+Alt+Space just changes the aggressiveness of the IntelliSense behavior.

Comment: @Serv , thanks for your reply, by unfortunate still i am facing that issue. i have tried the reset option

Answer (score 1):

You can try resetting the visual studio by using visual studio command prompt. take visual studio command prompt and enter this command **devenv /resetsettings**

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried the solution as you mentioned, but its not worked yet, still showing the same issue.

Comment: Even Microsoft can't reproduce the same to fix it(see the link in Serv's answer),its better to repair of re-install Visual Studio on your machine.