# No C#, no Unity 3D intellisense in Visual Studio Code in macOS after installing all requirements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I followed all the steps listed in [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) but I still have no intellisense. Not for C#, not for Unity 3D. What am I missing?

- VS Code version is 1.22.1
- OSX is 10.12.6
- Unity installation path is /Applications/Unity, version is 2017.3.1f1
- Installed dotnet-sdk-2.1.103-osx-x64
- Installed MonoFramework-MDK-5.8.1.0.macos10.xamarin.universal
- Installed extensions listed in screenshot 1
- Restarted
- Tried to delete csproj and sln files

Still nothing, see screenshot 2

When launched from Unity 3D, VS Code seems to load the entire solution successfully. Then, if I force intellisense suggestions popup by hitting CTRL+Space, I only get a *Loading...* for quite a while, then *No suggestions*.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Could you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420303/visual-studio-c-sharp-intellisense-not-automatically-displaying) solution?

Comment: It’s Visual Studio Code not Visual Studio

Comment: Off topic: you might try Visual Studio for Mac, which works extremely well for Unity.