# Visual Studio 2017 IntelliSense not working for Fortran language with Intel Parallel Studio

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intellisense

I recently re-installed Visual Studio due to some issues with the integration with Intel Parallel Studio. After reinstalling both, the integration issues are gone, but now for some reasons I have two issues. One is minor: automatic outlining has been disabled by default, and I have to re-enable it every time I start VS using `Edit` `>` `Outlining` `>` `Begin Automatic Outlining` (or something similar). Annoying, but at least it works.

The second issue however is that IntelliSense is not working. Under `Edit` `>` `IntelliSense`,  `Toggle Completion Mode` is grayed out. After reading the answer to [Visual Studio C# IntelliSense not automatically displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420303/visual-studio-c-sharp-intellisense-not-automatically-displaying), I followed the instructions and went to `Tools` `>` `Options` `>` `Text Editor` `>` `Fortran`. However all three of the check boxes are grayed out. Is this a known issue and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Has IntelliSense worked previously? I've never heard that IntelliSense supported Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is also related to the third party tool, I suggest you post the issue to the Intel® Visual Fortran Compiler forum, there you would get direct solution like this case:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/733588

In addition, a extension tool Fortran CodeNav which also add the IntelliSense feature, you could also use it in your side.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TiemenSchreuder.FortranCodeNav